# How to find the return value of a program after execlp()?

Tags: c, linux, exec

I have the following code in c:

`execlp("ReturnValue.c");`

ReturnValue.c should return an integer between 0-3, and since execlp won't return anything when the program successfully runs, how can I get the return value of that program?

Comment: Havind a *binary* executable named `ReturnValue.c` (with a `.c` extension) is poor taste. The `.c` extension is supposed to be for C source files!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
pid = fork();

if (pid == 0) {
    execlp("ReturnValue.c", ...);
}
else if (pid > 0) {
    waitpid(pid, &status, ...);

    /* extract the return status */
    WEXITSTATUS(status);
}
else { /* fork() error */ }
```

See [`waitpid(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/waitpid) or `man 3 waitpid`

Comment: Oh thanks, so "WEXITSTATUS(status)" is gonna be the return value? I can then do comparison like "if (WEXITSTATUS(status)) == 0)"?

Comment: Maybe read the `waitpid` manpage.  It tells you all you need to know...

Comment: @user3300198 Yes, I have added a link to the manual of `waitpid(3)`, you could follow that link to read that manual.