# In C, how to create multiple child processes (without knowing how many u need)?

Tags: c, linux, process, fork, pipe

Is it possible to create multiple child processes based on what happen in the parent process? For example, through a calculation in my parent process, I have decided I need 3 child processes, it may be 4,5 or 6. And then eventually pass integers one at a time into the child processes and get the exit values from them. Is there a way to implement this in C?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the return value of a program after execlp()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138007/how-to-find-the-return-value-of-a-program-after-execlp)

Comment: Yes. read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Comment: after calculating u can simply create as many child as u want.
Use a loop for creating as many child as u want, and for the child descriptor id variable u can take a integer pointer and allocate memmory to it in run time(The number of childs u want). and then using the loop simply create the childs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
int childs = 5; // I want 5 childs
pid_t pid;

while (childs > 0)
  {
    if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
      return (1); // handle this error as you want
    if (pid == 0)
      break;
    childs--;
  }
// the child go there directly
```

You can use an array/list of pid_t to remember all your childs and use waitpid to check their status.

edit :

way to handle childs differently and to remember them with an array:

```
int childs = 5; // I want 5 childs
pid_t pid[childs];
int i;

for (i=0; i < childs; ++i) {
  if ((pid[i] = fork()) == -1)
    return (1); // handle this error as you want
  if (pid[i] == 0) {
    break;
  }
 }
switch (i) {
 case 0:
   return(function0());
   break;
 case 1:
   return(function1());
   break;
 case 2:
   return(function2());
   break;
 case 3:
   return(function3());
   break;
 case 4:
   return(function4());
   break;
 default:
   ;
 }
```

I don't know exactly what you want to do, you can also use the modulo (%) operator in a condition to call the right function.
I use return there cause we don't want to stay in the for loop anymore, the 'functionx()' is going to do the whole new process job. You can also use in the function.

You now have an array of pid_t so you can check the status of your childs in a loop.

Comment: hmm.. How can I access each individual child then? Assuming I want to do different things in different childs

Comment: You can't really "access" it. If you want each of your child to execute a specific function you can simply use a counter and, depending of the value of this counter, call a different function. I'll edit my post with an example.