# How to get the return value of child process to its parent which was created using exec?

Tags: c, linux, exec, wait, waitpid

I have seen similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667095/how-to-get-the-return-value-of-a-program-ran-via-calling-a-member-of-the-exec-fa) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138007/how-to-find-the-return-value-of-a-program-after-execlp). The answers suggest to use WEXITSTATUS. But according to man page of WAIT(2), it has a limitation. It says:
WEXITSTATUS(wstatus)
              returns the exit status of the child.  **This consists of the least significant 8 bits of the status** argument that the child specified in a call to exit(3) or _exit(2) or as the argument
              for a return statement in main().  This macro should be employed only if WIFEXITED returned true.

So, if the child returns a value larger than 255, parent doesn't get the correct value. My question is how can a parent process receive the returned value which is larger than 255? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the o/s and its support for `SA_SIGINFO`.  If you read the specification of POSIX [`sigaction()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) carefully, and if you use `SA_SIGINFO` to capture extra information about the signals delivered, and you catch the `SIGCHLD` signal, then you *may* be able to get extra information, as documented in [Signal Actions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03) and [`<signal.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html).

In particular, the `<signal.h>` documentation notes that when the signal is `SIGCHLD`, then:

> `int si_status`
>
> If `si_code` is equal to `CLD_EXITED`, then `si_status` holds the exit value of the process; otherwise, it is equal to the signal that caused the process to change state. The exit value in `si_status` shall be equal to the full exit value (that is, the value passed to `_exit()`, `_Exit()`, or `exit()`, or returned from `main()`); it shall not be limited to the least significant eight bits of the value.

The documentation for Linux [`sigaction()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) indicates that this is supported on Linux.  It is, however, considerably harder to organize than using `waitpid()` or one of its family of functions, and I have not demonstrated that it really works as POSIX specifies.

Comment: See [How do I get information from `/proc` about a child process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52918189/) for some code which shows some use of `SA_SIGINFO` et al.  That particular context also accesses information from the `/proc` file system, but the code using the signal handling is independent of the access to `/proc` (but the access to `/proc` is not wholly independent of the signal handling — most of the alternative methods won't work reliably).

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how can a parent process receive the returned value which is larger than 255?

It can't.  The return value of a process **must** be from 0 to 255.  If you want to communicate any other value between a child and a parent, you need some form of interprocess communication such as pipes.